# animate from an auto start height to an unknown height?

Tags: jquery

I can try to throw this in a fiddle if necessary, it's just fairly convoluted code at the moment.
Here is my problem:
I have a child div that gets resized because of some dynamic image and text content, and a container parent that gives a nice border around the whole thing. The parent has an auto height (or no height?) so it flows with the child height. The problem is that when I change the child height, I am fading the content out and then back in, so the effective height is 12px (some borders going on). The parent resizes to 12, and then when the child content fades back in, the parent goes to the correct position. It just looks choppy, because you see this process unfolding in the span of 100ms or so. Is there any way to animate this process? I guess ideally I'm looking for something like

content.startAnimation and endAnimation, in which you don't have to specify values.

Comment: you'll have to set the height *before* the transition. jQuery can't animate from `auto`. try something like: `$el.height($el.height())`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Not sure how that would work, but in any case I tried it and no dice.

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with a solution.
Basically since my #content div was floating, I was able to put a #ghostWrapper div inside that could have a greater height than its parent (#content).
My #ghostWrapper was of course invisible. 
I start with this onClick:

```
// set content height on load
var contentHeight = $("#content").css("height");
$("#content").css("height", contentHeight);
```

Then once the content inside #ghostWrapper had auto adjusted the height of it, I set the height of #content equal to #ghostWrapper

```
// get ghostWrapper height and set content to it
var ghostHeight = $("#ghostWrapper").css("height");
$("#content").css("height", ghostHeight);
```

And in CSS I have height as a .2s transition so it adjusts seamlessly.
Hopes this helps anyone else with the same problem in the future.